# Combining elements at an index of an arraylist - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have three ArrayLists, each of which is of the same size:

```
arrayListOne   = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"}
arrayListTwo   = {"JKL", "MNO", "PQR"}
arrayListThree = {"STU", "VWX", "YZ0"}
```

I read and looked around, but I cannot seem to find a straightforward answer as to how to merge elements at the same index, and subsequently create a new `ArrayList` with the merged elements. As with the example,

```
arrayListMerged = {"ABCJKLSTU", "DEFMNOVWX", "GHIPQRYZ0"}
```

where `"ABCJKLSTU"` are the merged elements at index 0, `"DEFMNOVWX"` are the merged elements at index 1, and `"GHIPQRYZ0"` are the merged elements at index 2.

Perhaps this question has been answered before, however I am very new here, and still need to get to grips with certain ideas, which may have resulted in not understanding a previous answer.

Comment: I don't think that you can found a build-in function that do what you ask. I think you have to create your own

Comment: This is school homerwork? At least show us correct Java code

Comment: @r-rengold if you are a newbie at java I can give you some tips for the problem. I want to underline **give some tips** not write a copy/paste solution

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you are using ArrayList since they are not initialized that way...

Same concept should work on arraylist however

```
    String[] arrayListOne = { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" };
    String[] arrayListTwo = { "JKL", "MNO", "PQR" };
    String[] arrayListThree = { "STU", "VWX", "YZ0" };

    String[] arrayListMerged = new String[arrayListOne.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayListOne.length; i++) {
        arrayListMerged[i] = arrayListOne[i] + arrayListTwo[i] + arrayListThree[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayListMerged.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayListMerged[i]);
    }
```

Here is Java 8 way:

```
List<String> arrayListMerged = arrayListOne.stream()
                              .map(e -> arrayListTwo.get(arrayListTwo.indexOf(e)) + e + arrayListThree.get(arrayListThree.indexOf(e))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks Crazy ninja for the edit. I was looking for a zip(with) method in the stream API but couldn't find any. :( would have been nice to be able to a1.zip(a2,+).zip(a3,+) or something

Answer (score 1):

As you dint mention I am assuming all list have same size.

There no direct builtin function. Instead you can create a loop from `0` to size of any arrayList. Inside that loop extract the string values of all the list at the given loop index and concat all three then add that to new list(say newList) . Continue this for all loop iterations.

Answer (score 0):

So as each ArrayList has the same size just make a for loop which goes till the size of one ArrayList. `arrayListOne.size()` gives you the size of it.

With `arrayListOne.get(index)`, `arrayListTwo.get(index)`, `arrayListThree.get(index)` you get the values at the given index of the ArrayLists.

`arrayListMerged.add(*insert merged Strings here*)` adds the merged values to the new ArrayList.

Take a look at the API. It's well explained there https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not an out-of-the-box function in Java that does that. But it's fairly easy to implement your own. Here's how I would do it:

```
final int count = arrayListOne.length();

if(arrayListTwo.length() != count || arrayListThree.length() != count)
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Lists have different number of elements");

final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(count);
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    result.add(arrayListOne.get(i)+arrayListTwo.get(i)+arrayListThree(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 streams for this:

```
String[] arrayListOne   = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"};
String[] arrayListTwo   = {"JKL", "MNO", "PQR"};
String[] arrayListThree = {"STU", "VWX", "YZ0"};

String[] newList = new String[3];

Arrays.stream(arrayListOne).forEach(s ->
        {
            int index = Arrays.asList(arrayListOne).indexOf(s);
            newList[index] = s + arrayListTwo[index] + arrayListThree[index];
        } );
```

Or better way, don't use arrays, use `ArrayList`, so when you have lists which have different size, you can do this:

```
        ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayListOne = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayListTwo = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayListThree = new ArrayList<>();



        arrayListOne.forEach(s -> {
            int index = arrayListOne.indexOf(s);
            finalList.add(s + arrayListTwo.get(index) == null ? "" : arrayListTwo.get(index) + arrayListThree.get(index) == null ? "" : arrayListThree.get(index));
        });
```

Comment: @Jacek Cz No, this is not my school homework, please don't jump to conclusions which have zero factual basis :)

Comment: Everyone else: thank you again for the replies. Thank you for the link @Nico T.

Comment: @silentprogrammer I did mention that the lists are of the same length?...

Comment: @Viktor Mellgren I understand that ArrayLists are not initialised that way, they were there as an example, which could be generalised to broader concepts.